# How to set Windows Sound default settings for a device?

Tags: windows-7, audio, troubleshooting

In Windows Sound settings, is it possible to set the default settings for a sound playback device, such as the speaker configuration (7.1 vs Stereo) and the "Default Format" (e.g., 24 bit 48000Hz)?

If not, is there a way to configure a device so that it doesn't revert settings when the monitor is turned off? I have an HDMI-connected sound device that reverts to a Stereo/16bit/44000Hz configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think so:

- Open up playback devices in the audio settings
- right-click your device
- click properties
- go to the advanced tab
- There is a "Default Format" group box.
- Select what you want and hit apply!

I tried it with my headphones, unplugged them and then plugged them back in. They stayed to the changed format.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't set "defaults" -- this merely applies a setting to the current configuration. Upon rebooting the computer, the true "defaults" are restored (2.1 speaker config, 16bit/44Khz format). I'm trying to find where to permanently change and lock the defaults I need.