# Sound stutters with itunes when chrome is open

Tags: windows, google-chrome, itunes

When I listen to music with itunes and browse the web with chrome. The sound crackles constantly.

When chrome is closed the sound is just fine.
I have Windows 8.

I'm actualy a mac user so I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Turns out it was a buggy build.
[image: iTunes 12.1.1 update changes description]

---

If you're using iTunes 12.1 I think it's just a buggy release. macgicandre1981's remedy, as well changing the sound card's output format which worked for me in the past, are only temporary fixes on my Windows 8.1 computer.

You can try [changing the default format for the audio output](https://superuser.com/questions/575628/how-to-set-windows-sound-default-settings-for-a-device). But if it's already at the 16-bit 44.1 KHz setting, it's probably a shot in the dark. Worked for me a few times with random and differing settings.

The best bet seems to be rolling back to 12.0. There are a number of tips in this [Apple Discussions thread about the stuttering problem in Windows](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6765129?start=15&tstart=0). If you rollback, take heed of the corrupt library warning, as well as the source of the older version. The steps are in the [Further Information](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6562#more) link.

Comment: It looks like 12.0 is nowhere avalable. And when I want to install an even older iTunes version There'is a install error "There was a problem during install" :)

Comment: @Kaspar I'm just using foobar2000 for now, which I normally do when not wanting to hear my iPhone music. I think we'll have to wait. It wasn't a problem 10 seconds before upgrading.

Comment: @Kaspar 12.1.1 is now available from Apple.

Comment: This solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

When Chrome is using hardware acceleration, the Windows kernel uses a lot of CPU. This can causes your issues.

To solve it, run Chrome and [disable the hardware acceleration in the Chrome options](http://www.solveyourtech.com/turn-hardware-acceleration-google-chrome/).

[image]

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to have any effect. The stutters persist. It is stuttering when scrolling, while loading sites and while I write this on every type command.

Comment: capture a xperf trace: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Answer (score -1):

It happens when sound output is set to ASIO. Switching to another option (WASAPI or DS) does the trick though the sound quality changes (shouldn't with WASAPI but I feel it soudns worse thou). The more powerfull CPU, the less impact (I can compare betwen my old and new PC) but it still persists. Probably an ASIO bug...